# Haskell parsing using an accumulator with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

Haskell beginner here.

Say that I have a parser that I supply with some information and it returns the results of parsing a section and the info needed for the next section.

```
readSection :: Info -> Parser (Section, Info)
```

I was hoping to be able to parse multiple sections using the `many` combinator, but I can't get the types to work. I need some way of having a parser take in the `Info` of the previous computation. This structure reminds me of a fold (since the previous results can just be stored in the accumulator), but I'm not sure how to apply that here.

```
readSections :: Info -> Parser [Section]
readSections startInfo = do
  let parser = readSection startInfo
  -- ???
  return $ many readSection
```

Maybe there's a better way of doing something like this, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for an existing combinator, this looks like an application of `unfoldrM` from `monad-loops` (among other places).  To avoid having to import it, it can be defined as:

```
unfoldrM :: Monad m => (a -> m (Maybe (b, a))) -> a -> m [b]
unfoldrM f a = do
  r <- f a
  case r of
    Nothing -> return []
    Just (b, a') -> (b:) <$> unfoldrM f a'
```

Basically, it takes an initial seed of type `a` and uses it to monadically generate values and new seeds.  Your seed is your info:  you use the info to monadically generate a parsed section plus a new version of the info.

You just have to stick in an `optionMaybe` to provide the `Just`/`Nothing` switch so `unfoldrM` knows when it's reached the end of all the sections:

```
readSections = unfoldrM (optionMaybe . readSection)
```

However, as a Haskell beginner, it may be helpful to see how you do this sort of thing from scratch.  The `many` combinator isn't magical.  It's basically equivalent to the relatively simple monadic computation:

```
many p = (do x <- p
             xs <- many p
             return (x:xs))
         <|> return []
```

So, you can write `readSections` from scratch as a monadic computation in a similar manner:

```
readSections' :: Info -> Parser [Section]
readSections' i = (do -- try to read a section, getting updated info
                      (s, i') <- readSection i
                      -- read zero or more remaining sections with updated info
                      ss <- readSections' i'
                      -- return the sections
                      return (s:ss))
                  -- if no more sections to read, return an empty list
                  <|> return []
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be possible to write an "extended" version of `many` in an explicit way, but this answer uses [`StateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html) from "transformers" in order to reuse an already existing [`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) instance.

The function

```
readSection :: Info -> Parser (Section, Info)
```

Is quite reminiscent of what goes into the [`StateT` constructor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#t:StateT):

```
StateT :: (Info -> Parser (Section, Info)) -> StateT Info Parser Section
```

where `Info` would be the state and `Parser` the base monad. That is: each time we parse a `Section`, we modify the `Info` that the next parse attempt will use.

Furthermore, `StateT` has the following instance:

```
(Functor m, MonadPlus m) => Alternative (StateT s m)
```

If the base monad is a `MonadPlus` ([like `Parsec` is](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#t:ParsecT)) then `StateT` over the monad is an `Alternative`. This means that we can use [the `many` from `Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:many)—but not the more restricted `many :: ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m [a]` from "parsec".

So we wan write:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict

readSections :: Info -> Parser [Section]
readSections = evalStateT (Control.Applicative.many parser) 
  where
    parser :: StateT Info Parser Section
    parser = StateT readSection
```

Using [`evalStateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#v:evalStateT), which brings us back to a simple `Parser` and discards the final `Info` state.